# unltra-simplistic linear congruential random number generators

Tags: random

The real linear congruential number generators are more complicated but it is possible to generate a sequence that hits every number in 32 bits using only:

```
seed = seed * m + a
```

Obviously if m = 0 and a = 0, the sequence has length 1
if m = 1 and a = 1, the sequence counts through the entire range.

I experimentally determined that there are many numbers m and a around 32k, which must be odd, that have this property.  For example (from memory, hopefully I am right)

m = 32097, a = 31079

I wrote a small program and discovered that if m has this property, then there are many primes a that will work.

I do not yet know if for a working m, all prime numbers (except 2) will work.  I will test that empirically, but wondered whether there is some theory that would prove the results.

On the computer, I test that the sequence hits every number by the following simple test:

```
1. start with seed = 0
2. count 2^32 times.  For each time, calculate step 3
3. seed = seed * m + a
4. if seed == 0, break out, the sequence ends early
5. if after 2^32 iterations the sequence ends in 0, then every number must have been reached.
```

This mechanical proof won't work well for 64 bit numbers, so if anyone can prove that this is true, is there a way to determine the numbers m and a for which this will work without trying all 2^64  values?